# How to open a new window without refresh?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have this code implemented in my application, but whenever i click onto the link, it do help me open a new window. But the original page was "refresh", it kept go all the way back to the top. How can i resolve this problem?

code:

```
 Response.Write("<script>window.open('" + url + "')</script>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, each time you click the link the page is being send to the server where the event is handled (with some C#). If you do that, the server will send the whole page back.

You probably want to control this on client side, with some Javascript.

That said, what you are problably looking for is the attribute target of the link:

```
<a href="url" target="_blank">something</a>
```

That will tell the browser that you want to open another tab or windows when the user click the link, and then there request the page specified by url in that tab or window.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want Response.Redirect(myURL)

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the link and handle it in the code behind, that means the link is run at the server side, so it has to post back, which makes it look like it's "refreshing", but it's actually posting back.
You need to handle the opening of the new window on the client's side via Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If your're writing this to your page, this will redirect you to the url you want

```
Response.Write("<script>;location.href='" + url + "'</script>");
```